# Webpack Configuration: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to setup a webpack configuration for the first time. I am getting the error "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema" when i run the app. Here is the code in my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev";

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, "app");
const dirImages = path.join(__dirname, "images");
const dirVideo = path.join(__dirname, "videos");
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, "styles");
const dirShared = path.join(__dirname, "shared");
const dirNode = "node_modules";

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.join(dirApp, "index.js"), path.join(dirStyles, "index.scss")],

  resolve: {
    modules: [dirApp, dirShared, dirStyles, dirVideo, dirImages, dirNode],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      IS_DEVELOPMENT,
    }),
  ]
};
;
```

Here is the code in my webpack.config.development.js file

```
const path = require("path");

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const config = require("./webpack.config");

module.exports = merge(config, {
  node: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  },

  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
});
```

Comment: `merge` will accept configuration object. But in your config file you are not returning any object. Also, Are you using webpack 4/5? Change node: "production" to `mode:`

Comment: I am using webpack 5 @DhavalGajjar

Answer (score 1):

Change `node: "production"` to `mode: "production"` in `webpack.config.development.js` file.
Generally when you have wrong configuration then it will show this error. You can check configuration of Webpack at respective version [Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Also you used `merge` but it accept the config object to be merge while in your case `webpack.config.js` do not export any configuration.

I have used the updated configuration.

```
const path = require("path");

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const config = require("./webpack.config");

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  },

  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
});
```

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev";

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, "app");
const dirImages = path.join(__dirname, "images");
const dirVideo = path.join(__dirname, "videos");
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, "styles");
const dirShared = path.join(__dirname, "shared");
const dirNode = "node_modules";

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.join(dirApp, "index.js"), path.join(dirStyles, "index.scss")],

  resolve: {
    modules: [dirApp, dirShared, dirStyles, dirVideo, dirImages, dirNode],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      IS_DEVELOPMENT,
    }),
  ]
};
```

By using above configuration it build successfully. I don't have any data in `index.js` and `index.scss` file.

```
Webpack stats: asset main.js 0 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
./app/index.js 1 bytes [built] [code generated]
./styles/index.scss 1 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.78.0 compiled successfully in 170 ms
Your app is compiled in production mode in /dist. It's ready to roll!
```

Comment: I have exported it (check my edit) but i am still getting same error, I have also changed node to mode.